# WorldPay extension

Tags: payment-processor

Does anyone know of a working WorldPay extension? I know there was an alpha version developed by MillerTech in 2015 but unsurprisingly this doesn't work.  I would be surprised if a company has not paid for an extension to be developed for themselves.  We can contribute towards this but cannot afford to have this developed ourselves.

Answer (score 0):

We have one that we've been using for a few clients, we could share it if you needed one?

Comment: That would be wonderful if you could.  Could you contact me at ralph at bis-space.com please?